# PHP вывод массива

Tags: php

Есть массив `$data = array()`. В него записываются данные `array_push($data, data)`.

Т.к. `data` может повторяться, создаётся новый массив с уникальными `data`.

`$uniq_data = array_unique($data);`

После чего я хочу вывести этот массив. Делаю я это так :

```
for($i=0; $i<count($uniq_data); $i++){
}
```

Выводит только первые 2 элемента массива. После вывода массива через `print_r($uniq_data);` вижу что ключи элементов не идут по порядку (0,1,2,3...), видимо ключи копируются из прошлого массива(0,4,28,392...).

Я не понимаю как это работает. По идее оно должно вывести все элементы, но выводит только те, где ключ элемента массива меньше числа `count($uniq_data)`. Почему так? И как мне вывести все элементы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое после `array_unique` для сортировки ключей с нуля:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

`array_values()` возвращает массив со всеми элементами массива `array`. Она также заново индексирует возвращаемый массив числовыми индексами. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

Функция `array_unique()` удаляет повторяющиеся элементы, но **не** сбрасывает их индексы. Соответственно, если у вас 4 элемента в массиве, но их индексы равны, например: 0, 4, 28, 392, то в цикле `for` выведется только первый элемент.
Чтобы вывести все элементы воспользуйтесь циклом перебора массива `foreach`:

```php
foreach ($uniq_data as $key => $data) {
    //..
}
```

[Подробная информация в документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)